# ADFS 2016 - CORS issue for OpenID Connect Discovery Endpoint

Tags: angular, cors, .net-core, adfs4.0

I'm trying to set up our Angular SPA + .ASPNET Core API with ADFS (on premises) to get rid of windows authentication. Ultimately the goal would be:

- Angular SPA - > Redirects user to ADFS and receives id_token back
- Angular SPA - > Uses this token to call API
- Angular SPA - > Refreshes the token from time to time

The Angular SPA and API are correctly configured on ADFS. I'm using [angular-oauth2-oidc](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc) to configure the spa.

The issue is: when loading the SPA I get a CORS error when the SPA tries to reach the OpenId Discovery endpoint (`.well-known/openid-configuration`). So I cannot even redirect the user to ADFS. Nothing works.

I looked a lot online and only found lots of other people saying that ADFS doesn't support CORS. Seems strange though. Microsoft claims that they support [Single Page Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/single-page-application-with-ad-fs), so you already more or less assume that ADFS will be receiving CORS requests.

Has anyone else bumped into this issue? Seriously that Microsoft had implemented this and didn't built in a way to allow CORS requests?

**Edit:** I also tried creating a wrapper around adal.js. I managed redirecting the user to ADFS, logging in and  get the id_token. The issue now is that the sts returns the `aud` claim for the spa in the token, not for the api. When SPA uses the token to call the API it as expected fails. Feels like I have hit a dead end on this.

Comment: Hi, I'm hitting exactly the same dead end, did you finally found a solution for this issue ?

Comment: More or less.. I managed to make it work using adaljs. It's a long time ago.. and I don't work on it anymore so.. can't share much details :(. But you can search for angular adal package, pretty sure it's one of the first results.

Answer (score 3):

Not possible in ADFS 2016, not solved in ADFS 2018 (So far).

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/efcb35b3-f0f6-4c83-8a34-8e939aa56e7f/adding-cors-headers-to-oidc-discovery-endpoint-in-adfs-2016?forum=ADFS

Jeff

Comment: Solved in 2019, untested as I'm stuck on 2016 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/customize-http-security-headers-ad-fs